# Mesh edges become unsmooth/ jittery

Tags: mesh, subdivision-surface, error

[image]

[image]

Objects i draw in this file, lines become jitter, and i can't seem to find the exact probelm why. There doesn't seems to be anyone talking about it online.

Maybe i messed up the setting i dont know.

For example when i draw a jug on a new file subdivision surface works fine, but then when i draw any object on this project file, edges lines become jitter, unsmooth

link to the file :https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/yd2ab5qqnvub4pazunqbu/230716.blend?rlkey=v5x1ef3tsjf1rm5xj1o6fozoz&dl=0

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't post the same question more than once. If your previous question was put on hold, address the raised issues by editing it so it can be reopened rather than post a new one, otherwise see [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)

Comment: I suspect the problem is due to normal computational inaccuracies in the calculation of the vertex positions. That object has an x location of 28999680 mm and y location of -8177195 mm. If you zero all 3 locations you'll see that the distortions disappear.

Comment: I agree with John, your object is very far from the scene center, I don't know what is the technical reason but it makes the 3D view bug

Comment: thank youuu very muchhhhh guys!!!!

Comment: @moonboots The problem is floating point precision. This is not a problem of Blender, but a general limitation of how numbers are stored in computers. In short, you only have a limited amount of exact digits, for float its around 6-7, regardless of where the comma/point is. So for example you can have 0.12345 or 12345.0 but _not_ 12345.12345.

Comment: Oh ok thanks a lot for the explanation, i guess you can give it as an answer

Comment: @taiyo Yes. That's what I was thinking but couldn't remember the terminology!  (That's what happens when you're in your late 70s!) :^)